# need help with bizarre java.net.HttpURLConnection behavior

Tags: java, httpurlconnection

I am attempting to download a jpg using HttpURLConnection and am encountering a very peculiar bug.

Here's the url:
http://www.vh1.com/sitewide/promoimages/shows/m/my_antonio/video/supertrailer/seg_1/320x240.jpg

if you open it in a browser you will see the image.

However, when I use HttpURLConnection I don't get the image...
What I get is a 301 which, quite strangely, redirects to http://wap.vh1.com

so

```
    con.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);
//additional stream code here to go and get the stuff found in con
```

proceeds to go ahead and download the text from wap.vh1.com, rather than the jpg that you see in the browser.

I'm guessing that there is some header wackiness that's causing this, but I haven't the faintest idea what the host is expecting to see in order to redirect me to the same place as where it's redirecting the browser (and curl and wget and everything else I can think to point at it).

I'm just about ready to shoot myself, so, if you help me you will be preventing my 6 year old daughter from going fatherless.

Comment: Could you post your full code you are using to create the connection and fetch the URL?

Comment: there's a whole lot of it and it works for all other urls, so, I'm reluctant to clutter up the post with it... I'll add a few lines that are the most pertinent...

Comment: Seems like vh1 think your request is coming from a mobile device - are the other URLs that work for images?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The site redirects you based on user-agent. Add this before you open the connection,

```
conn.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; U; Intel Mac OS X 10.5; en-US; rv:1.9.0.15) Gecko/2009101600 Firefox/3.0.15");
```

Comment: I would just add that every "valid" desktop-client like useragent is allowed here and not explicitly Firefox on MacOS :)

Answer (score 1):

It seems like the server interprets your request as coming from a mobile device, possibly based on the  User-Agent header. That's why your redirected to the mobile site. Try setting the User-Agent explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

While I can't help you with your specific problem, here's what I would do:

- Download [wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/), sniff the HTTP request sent by your java application
- Copy/Paste the request, and run it with telnet (or a tool such as [WFetch](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=B134A806-D50E-4664-8348-DA5C17129210&displaylang=en))
- Fiddle with the request headers and see if behavior changes.

(I'd suspect the site screens the request based on the User agent header or something similar)

Comment: Another tool that can help in this sort of situation is the FireBug plug-in for Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

For more flexibility you can utilize the [http commons libraries](http://hc.apache.org/), which have great debugging support for the *wire* through log4j ...

Also, user agents and more request parameters can be set easily.

For more information, see [their tutorial](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client/tutorial/html/fundamentals.html).

Answer (score 0):

The java.net package doesn't support lot of the needed features out of the box (like automatically saving and sending cookies). Use Apache's [httpClient](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/) instead